# Regex don't replace

Tags: php, jquery, regex, expression

`"</div>                                                                                          ";`

and i want to replace the last  ... but, i have space lines after , if i remove the space lines, will working.. but i can't to remove space lines.. how i can replace last  with spacelines after him?

I tried this

```
 echo preg_replace ( "/<\/div>$/", "pula", $txt);
```

and still doesn't work.

i hope you will help me, thanks.

Comment: Post code here rather to get some help.

Comment: it's posted.. http://pastebin.com/eHX2mcrU

Comment: What's the nonsense of stackoverflow... That is not needed nor actually annoying! -_-

Comment: You code needs to be part of question. We can't work with a link.

Comment: don't me can't help no you try. php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo preg_replace ( "/<\/div>\s*$/", "pula", $txt);`